# Shadow variable in R

Tags: r, variables, scope, variable-assignment

I'd like to do something a bit unusual....

I've created a variable in the global scope, however, I'd like to use it in a function, from a string.

normally, I'd use

```
abc <- eval(parse(text=paste(test, "_ext", sep = "")))
```

and update whatever test_ext is with abc at the end of the function. In this particular case, that's not possible, so I'd like to create something where...

```
a <- 10 #global scope
b <- 5  #global scope
test <- function(letter)
{
    letter <<- letter + 10
}
test("b")
```

So as soon as `letter` is updated, then `b` would be updated.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than messing around with the global environment, you can create a custom environment containing only those objects that you want to manipulate. This avoids potentially causing lots of problems down the track, when you change a variable that you didn't want to change.

Something like this:

```
e <- new.env()
e$a <- 10
e$b <- 5

test <- function(letter)
{
    if(!exists(letter, e, inherits=FALSE)) stop("object ", letter, " not found")
    val <- get(letter, e) + 10
    assign(letter, val, e)
}
```

Comment: ah, that now makes a lot more sense. I was skeptical about using the global environment because of the obvious reasons and well, it just seemed like a terrible idea. However, using this will make things a lot tidier! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you **should** do this:

```
mylist <- list(a=10, b=5)
# $a
# [1] 10
# 
# $b
# [1] 5

test <- function(funlist,letter)
{
  funlist[[letter]] <- funlist[[letter]] + 10
  funlist
}

mylist <- test(mylist,"b")

mylist
# $a
# [1] 10
# 
# $b
# [1] 15
```

Sorry, but I won't support your bad practice by answering the question as you asked it. Functions should not have side effects in R (which means: don't use `<<-`).

Comment: Thanks for this. While I'm aware that using the global scope would be not the greatest Idea, I'm pretty new to R, wasn't aware that I could make custom environments for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Especially for beginners, it is important to learn that lists are often the way to go. It opens the way to some powerful tools, e.g., `lapply` and relatives. Normally you shouldn't use `get` and `assign` until you are more advanced. And `eval`/`parse` constructs should be avoided if possible.